Error message when compiling the type finder of another data class
I'm trying to display the following in my Offer Entity. However, I get the following error message when compiling the address in the console:

Could not determine recommended JdbcType for
de.stromee.orderup.offer.domain.OfferAddress

Why and what do I have to change to make it work?
Offer.tk
@Entity
@Table(name = "offers")
data class Offer(

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
val uniqueId: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),

var id: String,
var energyTyp:String,
var addresse:  OfferAddress,
...
var citys: List<OfferAddress>
)

OfferAddress.tk
@Entity
@Table(name = "offerAddress")
data class OfferAddress (

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 var uniqueId: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

 var id: Number,
 var name: String,
 var postcode: Number
)

